# Changing the color and near ocean with QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, borders, ocean

The border of region near ocean looks looks very fat. How can I change color of border lines near ocean to make it thicker? I want to change color and thikness of line only near oceans[image]

Comment: Do you have a borderline layer? If so, that would be the easiest way to do that. If you don't have it yet. Merge all your country layers and set the polygon to hollow, next just style the border like you want it.

Comment: If you want the change to appear **only near oceans** i don't see ways to do that ... apart of manually of course ...

Comment: You need a line layer of the coastlines.